# Looping through data in sql server that has been sent from angular ajax

Tags: sql, sql-server, ajax, angularjs

Sample data being sent:

```
 {
   "Demo":"A 25-54",
   "Headlines":
   {
     "0":"Headline one",
     "1":"Headline two"
   }
 }
```

Post request:

```
  $http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : 'api/endpoint',
    data    : $.param( availForm.formData ),
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).success(function(data) { alert('done'); }).
```

How the data is being presented to SQL:

[image: How the data is being presented to SQL]

I am able to get the posted "Demo" just fine since it is not nested, but how would I go about inserting the second headline via SQL?

**And note:** I am using SQL SERVER.

Comment: You probably want to show some of the code you have tried and what is working and what isn't if you hope to get some good feedback

Comment: You generaly want to avoid looping and string parsing in sql. There are several json parsers availabe for several platforms, I would try to get a data table structure from the json data and send it to sql server as a table typed parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended simply using this regular expression to trim out the encoded percent post request and make usable variables on the server.

```
String.prototype.trimAndCompact = function() {
return this
    // Remove whitespace start/finish
    .replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g, '')
    // Replace any double spaces with only one space
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
    // Remove %5D and %5B relevant to the percent encoding
    .replace(/%5B/g,'').replace(/%5D/g,'');
};
```

// notice the added trimAndCompact()

```
$http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : 'api/endpoint',
    data    : $.param( availForm.formData ).trimAndCompact(),
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).success(function(data) { alert('done'); });
```